# Using both Onkeyup and Onchange

Tags: javascript

I have two input boxes, one takes user input and multiplies it with 596 and then displays the result in the second input box while updating a `<span>` with the check if its PlanA or PlanB

```
function calculate() {
var ethBox = document.getElementById('eth').value; 
var myResult = ethBox * 596;
document.getElementById('usd').value = myResult.toFixed(2);

if(ethBox < 10){
document.getElementById('span').innerHTML ="PlanA";
    }else if(ethBox >= 11 && ethBox <=20){
document.getElementById('span').innerHTML ="PlanB";

    }
}
```

it work.

But I also want the user input in the second input box to be divided by 596 and display the result in the first input box, also updating the `<span>` with the conditional statement at the same time

```
function reverse() {
var usdBox = document.getElementById('usd').value; 
var myResult = usdBox / 596;
document.getElementById('eth').value = myResult.toFixed(2);

}
```

This code changes the value of the first input box but it doesnt update the `<span>`

Input Boxes

```
<input id="eth" onkeyup="calculate();" type="text">

<input id="usd" onkeyup="reverse();"  type="text">
```

The Span
`<span id="span"></span>`

I also tried using `onkeyup` and `onchange` for the first input box, which didn't work

Comment: What do you mean, "didn't work"? What did you do __exactly__? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? Did you get any errors?

Comment: There is no span shown for us to run this as a [mcve]. That leaves us to have to completely guess what problem is

Comment: @charlietfl i just edited the question and added the span

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following code in reverse function also. Added a common() method to do the task that is common to both methods.

```
    var ethBox = document.getElementById('eth').value; 
    if(parseInt(ethBox,10) < 10){
        document.getElementById('span').innerHTML ="PlanA";
    }else if(ethBox >= 11 && ethBox <=20){
        document.getElementById('span').innerHTML ="PlanB";
    }
```

```html
<script>
function calculate() {
  var ethBox = document.getElementById('eth').value; 
  var myResult = ethBox * 596;
  document.getElementById('usd').value = myResult.toFixed(2);

  common();
}

function reverse() {

  var usdBox = document.getElementById('usd').value; 
  var myResult = usdBox / 596;
  document.getElementById('eth').value = myResult.toFixed(2);

  common();
}

function common() {
 var ethBox = document.getElementById('eth').value; 
  if(parseInt(ethBox,10) < 10){
  document.getElementById('span').innerHTML ="PlanA";
  }else if(ethBox >= 11 && ethBox <=20){
  document.getElementById('span').innerHTML ="PlanB";
  }
}
</script>
<input id="eth" onkeyup="calculate();" type="text">

<input id="usd" onkeyup="reverse();"  type="text">

<span id="span"></span>
```

Comment: please can you explain `if(parseInt(ethBox,10) < 10){` a little

Comment: document.getElementById('eth').value function returns a string type of value, so you need to convert it to a number type format(before performing any inequality checks ). So parseInt basically converts the string type variable into an integer type. In case you want it to take decimal values also, then you can use parseFloat instead of parseInt